# How do you create a GUID in Lua script? using LuaPlus if that helps

Tags: c++, lua, guid

I am currently working on a project with LuaPlus and I need to be able to use GUIDs but cant seem to find them in lua.  When I am building data for lua there is no setGUID, there are set number, set string, etc.  there is also a Set() function.  Does anybody know the proper way to pass GUIDs from c++ to lua and lua to c++.  Thank you Very Much.

#### Update:

Thank you all for your responses. I appreciate the speedy responses. I wont actually be searching through the tables of actors often, mostly just on the front end when we load everything in. However, I am probably worrying a little too much because the game is kind of small and there wont be a large amount of actors anyways. I was thinking of writing an optimized string compare in lua where you check the first char of the GUID against the test actor. If it passes, then move to the second and so one. If it fails then move on to the next actor. I'm hoping by doing an optimized compare like this, I wont have to worry about any speed issues, at least for the game I am working on. Does this sound like a good idea compared to just a normal string compare?

Answer (score 1):

GUID is just 16 bytes. You can pass it as 16 chars for example. Why you need GUID in lua?

Comment: need GUIDs in lua to use as identifiers for our actors

Comment: lua strings are char arrays and can contain embedded '\0' characters so you can use these.

Comment: I understand this, but I was afraid this might slow down the game because of string compares.  So is there no GUID implementation in lua?  Do games that use it just use char arrays for the GUIDs if they are using GUIDs?

Comment: If you worry about speed of particular operation then write it in C/C++ and call from lua. Usually lua is used for scripting particular events not for doing low level object searches from big piles of objects.

Comment: @Matthew Poole: Strings comparisons in Lua are very fast. String interning might be slow, OTOH, if you do a lot of it. When you're worried about performance — write a benchmark.